# Increment Decrement operator use

Tags: java

In the below programs , post increment operator is used just after completion of expression evaluation. Now for the first program shouldn't the answer be 40 n then value of a be incremented to 41.N likewise for program 2 answer should be 41 instead of 42?

```
class IncrementDemo{
public static void main(String [] args){ 
    int a=20;
    a= a++ + a++;
    System.out.println(a); //Answer given is 41
}

class IncrementDemo{
public static void main(String [] args){ 
    int a=20;
    a= a++ + ++a; 
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer given is 42 for second program.

Answer (score 3):

You can understand the behaviour if you analyze how the statement is executed and the state of `a` in the meanwhile.

```
a = 20
a++ is executed, 20 is the result of the evaluation, a = 21
the second a++ is executed, 21 is the result, a = 22
the two results are added, 20 + 21 = 41, a = 41
```

on the other side, in the second case:

```
a = 20
a++ is executed, 20 is the result of the evaluation, a = 21
++a is executed, a = 22, 22 is the result
the two results are added, 20 + 22 = 42, a = 42
```

This is because the two increment operators are evaluated sequentially, so the second sees the effect of the first one.

Comment: ok and lets say int i=20 and then if i do i++ , in this case if i print value of i , it would be 21 directly right , it wont be 20?

Comment: If you do, let's say print(i++), yes, it prints 20. It you do i++;print(i) it prints 21

Comment: If you use a pre increment operator, it prints both times 21

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those two is, that `++a` will increment the value of a and return the incremented value. On the other hand `a++` will increment the value, but return the original value that a had before being incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a++ + a++
```

For the first `a++`, the value of `a` being used for the calculation is its actual value: 20, and after that it is incremented to 21.
So, for the second `a++`, the value used for the calculation, is also the actual value of `a`, but this time it is 21 because it has been incremented in the first `a++`.

So you have 20 + 21, hence 41.

```
a = a++ + ++a
```

Same thing for `a++`, the actual value of `a`, 20 is used for the calculation, and then it is incremented to 21.
Then `++a`, the value is incremented before it is used, so it becomes 22, and then it is used for the calculation.

So you have 20 + 22, hence 42.

Answer (score 0):

The results are correct.

### First case

```
int a=20;
a= a++ + a++;
```

This results in the following evaluation steps:

- `a = a++ + a++` (with `a=20`)
- `a = 20 + a++`  (with `a=21`)
- `a = 20 + 21`   (with `a=22`)

### Second case

```
int a=20;
a= a++ + ++a;
```

This results in the following evaluation steps:

- `a = a++ + ++a` (with `a=20`)
- `a = 20 + ++a`  (with `a=21`)
- `a = 20 + 22`   (with `a=22`)

Answer (score 0):

> When operator used in prefix mode, it increments the operand and
>   evaluates to the incremented value of that operand. When used in
>   postfix mode, it increments its operand, but evaluates to the value of
>   that operand before it was incremented.

```
a= a++ + a++;
```

so **first** a++ will yield 20, now a value become 21

**second** a++ will yield 21, so final operation return 20+21 = 41

similar for second program

```
 int a=20;
 a= a++ + ++a;
```

**First** a++ will yield 20, now a value become 21

**second** ++a will yield value 22

combining both will return result 20+22 = 42